# Не работает livereload

Tags: gulp

Не работает `livereload` в браузере.

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
concatCss = require('gulp-concat-css'),
minifyCss = require('gulp-minify-css'),
autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer'),
notify = require('gulp-notify'),
connect = require('gulp-connect');

//connect server
gulp.task('connect', function() {
  connect.server({
    root: 'gulp-project',
    livereload: true
  });
});

//css
gulp.task('css', function() {
 return gulp.src('./*.css')
    .pipe(concatCss("bundle.css"))  
    .pipe(minifyCss())
    .pipe(autoprefixer({
        browsers: ['last 25 versions'],
        cascade: false
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('out/'))
    .pipe(notify("Done!"))
    .pipe(connect.reload());
});

//html
gulp.task('html', function() {
    return gulp.src('index.html')
    .pipe(connect.reload());
})

//watch
gulp.task('watch', function() {
    gulp.watch('*.css',['css'])
    gulp.watch('index.html',['html'])
});

gulp.task('default',['connect','html','css','watch'])
```

Comment: Что выводит в консоли браузера?

Comment: Ничего не выводит. Ошибок и предупреждений нет.

Comment: Тогда нужно установить плагин gulp-livereload для Gulp и подключить его livereload = require('gulp-livereload')

Comment: Добавил. К сожалению, не помогло.

Comment: А у вас на самой HTML странице то подключен скрипт, который слушает лайврелоад?

Comment: Да, подключен. Но я думаю, даже без него должен работать.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д.